# what "C2F(ddot)" the meaning in scilab

Tags: scilab

i download the scilab sourcecode, i am interested how the conv2 works and want translate it to c# code, but i don't know what the meaning of "C2F(ddot)" and how it works. if i tranfer the "C2F(ddot)" into c or c# code how i should implement it. here are some piece of source code in scilab

```
extern double C2F(ddot)(int *n, double *A, int *iA, double *B, int *iB);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void conv2_separable_R(double *R, int nR, double *C, int mC, double *A, int mA, int nA, double *Out, int mOut, int nOut, int edgM, int edgN, double *T)
{
    int ai = 0, tj = 0, ci = 0, rj = 0; /*current index over A,T,C and R */
    int i = 0, j = 0; /* loop variables*/
    int l = 0;
    int one = 1, minusone = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < mOut; i++ )
    {
        /*Compute  the 1-D conv A(i,:) and C  in T */
        ai = Max(0, i - edgM) ;
        ci = mC - 1 - Max(0, edgM - i);
        l = Min(ci + 1, mA - ai);
        for (j = 0; j < nA; j++ )
        {
            T[j] = C2F(ddot)(&l, A + ai + mA * j, &one, C + ci - l + 1, &minusone);
        }
        /*1-D convolution of T and  R */
        for (j = 0; j < nOut; j++ )
        {
            rj = nR - 1 - Max(0, edgN - j);
            tj = Max(0, j - edgN) ;
            l = Min(rj + 1, nA - tj);
            Out[i + j * mOut] = C2F(ddot)(&l, T + tj, &one, R + rj - l + 1, &minusone);
        }
    }
}
```

if i want tranform the code:" T[j] = C2F(ddot)(&l, A + ai + mA * j, &one, C + ci - l + 1, &minusone);" into c or c# ,how i should do ?

Answer (score 0):

In scilab's sources, `C2F` is a macro used to call Fortran function from C.

It's declared [in `machine.h`](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/sCiMake/source/tree/47a86ccede07d38b29f26c8038763f60aef0c0e0/scilab-5.2.0/modules/core/includes/machine.h.vc).

Actually this code probably make a call to [the Blass `ddot` function](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/sci-ipopt/source/tree/ad23f2f9de459fb27c956a7539bf5bf118716783/thirdparty/Ipopt-3.8.1/ThirdParty/Blas/ddot.f).

That it, the dot product of two vector is done in Fortran...